# Unity: Editor Application Instalation Failed, Install Failed

Tags: unity-game-engine

So Ive tried downloading editor to START USING UNITY, but it seems impossible. If I download it from Unity Hub I get an error that says Editor Application ,Instalation Failed Install failed.

I followed some online tutorial that told me to turn off the firewall and stuff didnt worked.

Then I followed another tutorials explaining that I should instead install them from unity's page. When I did it worked (or so I thought) . But when trying to make a new project I got the prompt telling me to go to Safe Mode

If I ingored it, cause I obviously wanted to use all features, there was a compiling error and a (unity internal Build  System error.Backened with code 2)

I tried downloading some older version, but once I did I got a problem with my Tile Palette
(Dont think it is related, dont really know, but worth to mention)
The tile palette didnt appear in the newer versions, even after downloadong and redownloading Tile Map Editor

In the older version it appeared, but once I pressed play, somehow the pallete stoped working and dissapeared

Idk, guess Unity in my pc is really fucled up, tried deleting everything and reinstalling unity

Bu, guess what....

Ive tried everything on the web , everything I understand so far

Comment: Unity has had problems in the past when the project you create or open is in a directory with spaces or that has non-ascii characters in it. Hopefully they've fixed those, but just in case try creating the project in a directory without any of that, like `c:\projects\whatever`. You might also take a look in the editor.log file when you have issues to see if there are any clues. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html